# Java issue with Exception not being handled (functional interface with lambdas)

Tags: java, exception, lambda, functional-interface

I really need some help.
This is my functional interface:

```
/**
 * This class represents a filter.
 */
@FunctionalInterface
interface FileFilter {
    /**
     * This method gets a file path and filters it in some method.
     * @return a list of the remaining files after this filter.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    abstract boolean filter(Path path) throws IOException;
}
```

This is the lambda function that I've written:

```
    static FileFilter modeFilter(String value, boolean containsNo, Predicate<Path> pathMethod)
    throws IOException{
        if (value.equals(YES)) {
            if (containsNo) {
                return path -> !pathMethod.test(path);
            } else {
                return path -> pathMethod.test(path);
            }
        }

        if (containsNo) {
            return path -> pathMethod.test(path);
        }
        return path -> !pathMethod.test(path);
    }
```

I am giving the filter this parameters:

```
Filters.modeFilter(commandParts[1], containsNOT, x -> Files.isHidden(x))
```

The problem is that I get a compliation error in Files.isHidden that says that there is an Excpetion not handled - IOExeption.

I made sure that the method that calls modeFilter throws IOExeption, so this is not the problem.
How do I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method takes a `Predicate<Path>` as argument.

The signature of the Predicate function is

```
boolean test(T)
```

But the signature of [Files.isHidden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isHidden-java.nio.file.Path-) is

```
boolean isHidden(Path path) throws IOException
```

So they don't match: a predicate is not supposed to throw an IOException, but `Files.isHidden()` can.

Solution: pass a FileFilter as argument, rather than a `Predicate<File>`, since the only reason `FileFilter` exists is precisely so that it can throw an IOException, unlike a Predicate.

Note that the `modeFilter` method has no reason to throw an IOException: all it does is creating a FileFilter. It never calls it. So it can't possibly throw an IOException.

Comment: I need to create a FileFilter according to these conditions.. So how do I modify the passed FileFilter to the different options? How do I create a new lambda based on the given one?

Comment: Replace `Predicate<Path> pathMethod` by `FileFilter pathMethod`. And replace `pathMethod.test(path)` by `pathMethod.filter(path)`.